# Regular expression for splitting a String and getting the last part

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a String which is a file's name (ex: DIS_LU0786738343_20170608.pdf, KID_AMEV_20170608.pdf, Evolution-DIS_20170512.csv, Offres-invest_20170608.csv, OST_20170608.csv) to get the last part.

For example for the String `DIS_LU0786738343_20170608.pdf` I want to get only `20170608` which will be transformed on a `Date` object.

I've been googling this and I found a solution using `Regular Expressions`:

```
String regex = "some regex expression";
String fileName = "DIS_LU0786738343_20170608.pdf";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileName.split(regex)));
```

This will return an Array like this : `[DIS_LU0786738343_, 20170608]`

So anyone can help me make the Regular Expression to do so ?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service

Comment: @Fallenhero you're comment is not helpful :)

Comment: follow this next time https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped down the RegEx thing and found another solution that I want to share with anyone who'll need it in the future :

```
private LocalDate getDateFromPriipsDoc(File file) {
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
   String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.toString());
   String dateInString = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
   return LocalDate.parse(dateInString, formatter);
}
```

Do not hesitate to share another solution with RegEx ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String fileName = "DIS_LU0786738343_20170608.pdf";
    int startIdx = fileName.lastIndexOf("_");
    int endIdx = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    String finalStr=fileName;
    if (startIdx > 0 && endIdx > 0)
            finalStr = fileName.substring(startIdx + 1, endIdx);
    System.out.println(finalStr);
```

I think this should work for you.